# Vagrantfile location path - where is it defined and how to change it? (Windows)

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, path, host, vagrant

I have a Windows machine that I am using to host Virtual Box VMs used with Vagrant.

I'd like to keep Vagrant setup files including Vagrant all under a separate folder so that it is easy to know where to find everything. Where is the location path defined (so that I can alter it?)

Thanks.

Comment: Why is this *off topic* ? This is about *CONFIGURING A SERVER* !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:
Vagrantfile et al can be anywhere you like - where you create a folder and initialise Vagrant with in it:

*On the host machine*, create a folder, e.g.:

```
mkdir lamp-project
```

initialise vagrant in this folder

```
cd lamp-project
vagrant init
```

It's a bit like git in that respect where you initialise the repository where you are going to work in.